# functions.php getting modified randomly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a strange issue with my functions.php file which, every 30 minutes or so, loses about 10 lines in the middle of the file, which causes this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mm' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/thebueno/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 192

The file is getting modified in exactly the same way even after I restore the file.

I'd like to ask the experts if you would look at a particular culprit? WHat does your gut tell you given the circumstances? Nothing has been changed on this server for months. Suddenly, a file is modified in the strangest way: not truncated, but 10 lines taken out starting at line 192.

What modifies internal WordPress files automatically?

Comment: `What modifies internal WordPress files automatically?` virus?

Comment: That would be my guess, too. Something might be on the server or has access to it.

Comment: That was what my gut was telling me, but I know too little about WordPress and wanted to bring it up with you guys. This is an emergency debug for a friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hack that is going around; there are many instances of users recovering from it in the wordpress.org forums.

There are no known WP vulnerabilities right now, but your shared host or VPS is being exploited. The hackers are trying to add a php function to WP's functions.php file to serve malware or spam links.

You need to completely clean the hack and change access privileges or you will be hacked again. Work your way through these resources and follow all instructions to completely clean your site or you may be hacked again. See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress)

Change all passwords. Scan your own PC. Use http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/ before and after.

Tell your web host you got hacked; and consider changing to a more secure host: [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)

Comment: Hey songodgtech, I very much appreciate your answer. Thank you! This is exactly the type of expert opinion I was looking for. For those familiar with the framework, these symptoms identify a trend. As you say, there is identified JS injection going on here. I will suggest they change platforms.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how likely do you think this is that it's NOT a WP vulnerability given the huge amounts of random plugins people use? Are WP plugins sandboxed enough to not allow filesystem mods?

Comment: @yuji, hope that was useful. As far as I've seen as a wordpress.org forum moderator, it's really not a WP vulnerability right now. There are some hacks that occur from "bad" plugins, but from what I've seen, they're rare, and if they occur, they're from third party plugins that are not available in the wordpress.org plugin directory. Plugins can do all kinds of file system writes; WP admins can do fire system writes from the admin backend.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that your WordPress installation has been hacked. Most WordPress hacks seem to modify functions.php.

I would recommend downloading a fresh copy, deleting your installation, and installing your new copy.

Comment: "...downloading a fresh copy, deleting your installation, and installing your new copy" is *not* a complete fix.